# f2py fails if a function argument passed to another function

Tags: python, numpy, fortran, f2py

Here is my Fortran code:

```
!WRONG
function fun1(myfun1)
    implicit none
    real(8) :: fun1
    real(8),external :: myfun1
    fun1 = myfun1(1)
    return
end function fun1

function fun2(b,myfun2)
    implicit none
    real(8):: b,fun2
    real(8),external:: myfun2,fun1
    b = fun1(myfun2)
    fun2 = b
    return
end function fun2
```

I'm using `f2py` to build a Python module, that is `f2py -c -m test test.f90 -L"D:\mingw64\bin" --fcompiler=gnu95`. However, I got `"Warning Msg: Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with #define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION"` and failed to build a `.pyd` file. And this won't happen if there is no argv `myfun2` in my Fortran code, that is

```
!RIGHT
function fun1(a)
    implicit none
    real(8) :: fun1,a
    fun1 = a
    return
end function fun1

function fun2(b,myfun2)
    implicit none
    real(8):: b,fun2
    real(8),external:: myfun2,fun1
    b = myfun2(fun1(b))
    fun2 = b
    return
end function fun2
```

From that above I can get the correct `.pyd` file.
By the way, if I use `f2py -c test -h test.pyf test.f90` for the wrong Fortran code, I get the `.pyf` file as below.

```
!    -*- f90 -*-
! Note: the context of this file is case sensitive.

python module fun2__user__routines 
    interface fun2_user_interface 
        function myfun2(fun1_b_) result (b) ! in :test:test.f90:fun2:unknown_interface
            real :: fun1_b_
            real(kind=8) :: b
        end function myfun2
    end interface fun2_user_interface
end python module fun2__user__routines
python module test ! in 
    interface  ! in :test
        function fun1(a) ! in :test:test.f90
            real(kind=8) :: a
            real(kind=8) :: fun1
        end function fun1
        function fun2(b,myfun2) ! in :test:test.f90
            use fun2__user__routines
            real(kind=8) :: b
            external myfun2
            real(kind=8) :: fun2
        end function fun2
    end interface 
end python module test

! This file was auto-generated with f2py (version:1.22.1).
! See:
! https://web.archive.org/web/20140822061353/http://cens.ioc.ee/projects/f2py2e
```

It seems like that there is something wrong with the interface, but I'm not sure what to do.

Below is the full error message (I ran it again on linux, getting the same result):

```
running build
running config_cc
unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
running config_fc
unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
running build_src
build_src
building extension "test" sources
f2py options: []
f2py:> /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c
creating /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6
Reading fortran codes...
        Reading file 'test.f90' (format:free)
Post-processing...
        Block: test
                        Block: fun1
                        Block: fun2
Post-processing (stage 2)...
Building modules...
        Building module "test"...
                Creating wrapper for Fortran function "fun1"("fun1")...
                Constructing wrapper function "fun1"...
sign2map: Confused: external myfun1 is not in lcb_map[].
append_needs: unknown need 'myfun1'
append_needs: unknown need 'myfun1'
                  fun1 = fun1(myfun1,[myfun1_extra_args])
                Creating wrapper for Fortran function "fun2"("fun2")...
                Constructing wrapper function "fun2"...
sign2map: Confused: external myfun2 is not in lcb_map[].
append_needs: unknown need 'myfun2'
append_needs: unknown need 'myfun2'
                  fun2 = fun2(b,myfun2,[myfun2_extra_args])
        Wrote C/API module "test" to file "/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c"
        Fortran 77 wrappers are saved to "/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/test-f2pywrappers.f"
  adding '/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.c' to sources.
  adding '/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6' to include_dirs.
copying /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.c -> /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6
copying /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/f2py/src/fortranobject.h -> /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6
  adding '/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/test-f2pywrappers.f' to sources.
build_src: building npy-pkg config files
running build_ext
customize UnixCCompiler
customize UnixCCompiler using build_ext
get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu95', 'intel', 'lahey', 'pg', 'nv', 'absoft', 'nag', 'vast', 'compaq', 'intele', 'intelem', 'gnu', 'g95', 'pathf95', 'nagfor']'
customize Gnu95FCompiler
Found executable /usr/bin/gfortran
customize Gnu95FCompiler
customize Gnu95FCompiler using build_ext
building 'test' extension
compiling C sources
C compiler: gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC

creating /tmp/tmp28eupotb/tmp
creating /tmp/tmp28eupotb/tmp/tmp28eupotb
creating /tmp/tmp28eupotb/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6
compile options: '-I/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6 -I/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c'
gcc: /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c
gcc: /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.c
In file included from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.c:2:
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^
In file included from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarraytypes.h:1822:0,
                 from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/ndarrayobject.h:12,
                 from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/arrayobject.h:4,
                 from /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/fortranobject.h:13,
                 from /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:15:
/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_1_7_deprecated_api.h:17:2: warning: #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " "#define NPY_NO_DEPRECATED_API NPY_1_7_API_VERSION" [-Wcpp]
 #warning "Using deprecated NumPy API, disable it with " \
  ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c: In function ‘f2py_rout_test_fun1’:
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:327:3: error: unknown type name ‘myfun1_typedef’
   myfun1_typedef myfun1_cptr;
   ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:342:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   myfun1_cptr = F2PyCapsule_AsVoidPtr(myfun1_capi);
               ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:344:17: error: ‘myfun1’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   myfun1_cptr = myfun1;
                 ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:344:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:347:25: error: ‘myfun1_nofargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   myfun1_nofargs_capi = myfun1_nofargs;
                         ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:52: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                    ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:63: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                               ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:53: error: ‘maxnofargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                     ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:65: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                                 ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:76: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                                            ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:348:66: error: ‘nofoptargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun1_capi,myfun1_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun1_nofargs,&myfun1_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun1.")) {
                                                                  ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:359:3: warning: passing argument 2 of ‘f2py_func’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   (*f2py_func)(&fun1,myfun1_cptr);
   ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:359:3: note: expected ‘double * but argument is of type ‘int’
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c: In function ‘f2py_rout_test_fun2’:
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:427:3: error: unknown type name ‘myfun2_typedef’
   myfun2_typedef myfun2_cptr;
   ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:445:15: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
   myfun2_cptr = F2PyCapsule_AsVoidPtr(myfun2_capi);
               ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:447:17: error: ‘myfun2’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   myfun2_cptr = myfun2;
                 ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:450:25: error: ‘myfun2_nofargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   myfun2_nofargs_capi = myfun2_nofargs;
                         ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:52: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                    ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:63: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                               ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:53: error: ‘maxnofargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                     ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:65: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                                 ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:76: error: stray ‘#’ in program
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                                            ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:451:66: error: ‘nofoptargs’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   if (create_cb_arglist(myfun2_capi,myfun2_xa_capi,#maxnofargs#,#nofoptargs#,&myfun2_nofargs,&myfun2_args_capi,"failed in processing argument list for call-back myfun2.")) {
                                                                  ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:462:3: warning: passing argument 3 of ‘f2py_func’ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
   (*f2py_func)(&fun2,&b,myfun2_cptr);
   ^
/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c:462:3: note: expected ‘double *’ but argument is of type ‘int’
error: Command "gcc -pthread -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -D_GNU_SOURCE -fPIC -fwrapv -fPIC -I/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6 -I/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/include/python3.6m -c /tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.c -o /tmp/tmp28eupotb/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.o -MMD -MF /tmp/tmp28eupotb/tmp/tmp28eupotb/src.linux-x86_64-3.6/testmodule.o.d" failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour].

Comment: Please show us the complete output when f2py fails. The warning itself is just a warning. Look for some actual error message but better simply show everything.

Comment: It is quite possible that f2py simply doea not understand this convoluted passing of function arguments.